# cannot connect wireless in virtualbox ( windows host , mac guest )

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am new to virtual box.. I am using mac os snow lep as  a guest os  and  windows XP as my host in virtual box ,  I can connect my internet via ethernet , but  i could not connect via wireless. its giving error , i cant see wireless profile in mac os snow lep which is been visible in windows XP . can any one tell me the setting to be done in virtual box ;)

Can any one please guide me to solve this problem.

Awaiting for your favourable reply,

Regards,
Dilip Anand

Comment: The OS inside the VirtualBox is the guest, and the OS inside which VirtualBox runs is the host.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ONLY IN ADAPTER 1, unselect all the other adapter only 1. Then select attach to NAT, open advance settings and your adpater Type should be the FIRST or SECOND. IT WORKED FOR ME. THIS IS FOR MAC ONLY, and windows XP on virtualbox problem.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is going to the Network Adapter settings and in Adapter 1, unselect then select "Cable Connected." For some reason, that allowed the internet in Windows 7 to suddenly connect.

Answer (score 1):

OS X is not supported under VirtualBox by Oracle or Apple. While certain aspects of it can be made to work, I have not seen any support for wireless adapters.

Your best bet is to just configure the VirtualBox guest settings to use NAT networking on the virtual network adapter and let it manage the connections.

Comment: @ goyuix thanks for ur reply.. i did "NAT" in adapter 1 ... and bridge in adapter 2 ....moreover i attached my wireless adapter (USB) in virtualbox ... but no result ... can u seggest me some other suggestion plzzz

Answer (score 1):

This issue is essentially due to a the allocation of the same IP addresses to both the Host WiFi adapter (by the wifi router's DHCP server) and the Guest interface (by the VirtualBox DHCP server under Nat networking).

From the VirtualBox documentation about the integrated DHCP server [Fine-tuning the VirtualBox NAT engine](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat):

```
In NAT mode, the guest network interface is assigned to the IPv4 range 10.0.x.0/24
by default where x corresponds to the instance of the NAT interface +2. So x is 2
when there is only one NAT instance active. In that case the guest is assigned to the 
address 10.0.2.15, the gateway is set to 10.0.2.2 and the name server can be found at
10.0.2.3.
```

Looking at your host's WiFi adapter's IP address you will find that the address assigned to it is from the `10.0.2.0/24` network range as well.

This is the reason for the issue as now the Nat driver for VirtualBox is confused by the fact that the host and guest addresses are from the same subnet.

To fix this you can change the subnet served out by the VirtualBox DHCP server using the VBoxManage command(while the VM is powered down):

```
Vboxmanage modifyvm VMName --natnet1 "192.168/16"
```

And you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Mac, what I did was to change the Windows wireless settings to manual, so I set my IP, Gateway and DNS with the "right" settings.

Hope it works for you to!

Answer (score 0):

What Katrina A said, but I left "cable connected" checked.
Never had a problem until upgrading to version 4.3.6

Upgraded for USB support which did not work so well.
I found that if I  ejected my flash drive on the Mac, then went to VB settings > Ports > USB and unchecked the flash drive on the list (or any other device) the flash drive loaded into the VM.

The whole checking and unchecking thing seems good!

Answer (score 0):

On top of the solutions posted here, I would add that it fixed my problem to connect to my phone using a hotspot rather than the company's network.

It appears some Internet Service Providers may restrict the connection to virtual machines.